# Pagination prob in Grails

Tags: grails, pagination

I want to display all games under a certain category in pagination (10/page)
This is my controller

```
def listGame(){
    def category = GameCategory.list()
    def platform = Platform.list()
    def currentCategory = params.categoryName
    def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(currentCategory)
    def games = myCategory.games

    [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, games:games,  platforms:platform, gameCount:Game.count(), chosenPlatform:params.platform] 
}
```

and this is my pagination code in my view

```
<g:each in="${games}" status="i" var="game">
    ${game.gameTitle}
</g:each>
<div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate action="listGame" total="${gameCount}" />
</div>
```

When I have 9 games in the current category the page 12 showed up wherein it shouldn't

When I have 11 games in the current category all 11 games are displayed in page 1 and clicking page 2 will result in this error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to address.

1. Make sure `categoryName` is not coming into the controller as `null`.
2. Make use of the `max` and `offset` parameters that the paginator is providing to select the appropriate `Game`s.

## The category name

Because the paginator is creating the URL that calls into the controller, and your controller needs the category name, the paginator must add the category name to the params it calls the controller action with. You can achieve this with the tag's `params` attribute:

```
<g:paginate action="listGame" total="${gameCount}" params="${[categoryName: currentCategory]}"/>
```

## Max & offset

The controller needs to use `max` and `offset` parameters to know what subset of the `Game`s to retrieve from the database and render in the view. However, in some cases, such as when visiting the URL http://blah/someController/listGame, there would be no `max` and `offset` params. This is something your controller action must be able to handle. It goes something like this:

```
def max = params.max ?: 10
def offset = params.offset ?: 0
```

So the `max` and `offset` params will be used if they are available. Otherwise they'll use default values.

Finally, you need to use these parameters to select the `Game`s. For that you can use a *where* query:

```
def games = Game.where {
    categories.categoryName == currentCategory
}.list(max: max, offset: offset)
```

Something interesting about the returned `games` object: It acts like a list, but it's actually a `grails.gorm.PagedResultList`. That's a good thing because it contains the *total* number of records in the result (ignoring max and offset). In other words, it's your new `gameCount`.

You can read more about [where](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) queries in the Grails documentation. I also have a series of [articles](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/) which cover where, criteria and HQL queries in more detail.

Putting it all together, `listGame()` would look like this:

```
def listGame(){
    def category = GameCategory.list()
    def platform = Platform.list()
    def currentCategory = params.categoryName
    def max = params.max ?: 10
    def offset = params.offset ?: 0
    def games = Game.where {
        categories.categoryName == currentCategory
    }.list(max: max, offset: offset)

    [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, games:games,  platforms:platform, gameCount:games.totalCount, chosenPlatform:params.platform] 
}
```

Comment: Thaaanks!! I appreciate the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't done your homework. Please go through [grails doc](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/paginate.html) and other tutorials, to understand how pagination works.

Just to give you a hint. You are doing two things wrong here.

1. You are not getting a paginated list at the first place from controller
2. You are not sending back all the required data back to the controller, from the pagination link. And that's the reason you are getting the error!

Comment: im confused
1. In the docs the controller only pass list and count which I have which are [games:games, gameCount:Game.count()]
2. How to send back required data from pagination link?  in the docs its just <g:paginate controller="book" action="list" total="${bookCount}" />