# Initial display of pagination won't work in Grails

Tags: grails

This is my action

```
 def list() {
     def max = params.max ?: 3
     def offset = params.offset ?: 0
      def taskList = Game.createCriteria().list(params){
        if ( params.query) {
          ilike("gameTitle", "%${params.query}%")
          println "here task"
        }
        order("gameTitle", "asc")

      }     

      def total= userList.totalCount + taskList.totalCount
    [ totals:total, games: taskList, taskInstanceTotal: taskList.totalCount]
 }
```

This is how it would be displayed

```
<g:each in="${users}" status="i" var="user">
<h5 style="    padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">${user.name }</h5>
</g:each>
<g:paginate total="${taskInstanceTotal}" max="3" params="${params}"/>
```

After calling the controller, list of all results are displayed initially & also when I clicked on the pagination button it seems to be working fine. My problem is that it won't displayed properly after the data sent from the controller [it displays everything from my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCMVp.png) but when the pagination button is clicked it seems to be working fine.[After the pagination is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cgDo.png).

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656126/pagination-prob-in-grails/33662719#33662719

Comment: did some condition in my view and it works correctly